# Merging two pandas dataframes with two-term index returns non-unique keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, dask

**EDIT**

I wrote this post thinking that the issue was on `merge()` or `join()`, however the issue was on the results obtained from `groupby()`. If you found this post, there is a change that you're getting the same error for the same reason. Hence, I left the title unchanged.

**Original post**

I have two pandas dataframes that contain three columns each. The types are:

```
A: category
B: uint32
C: uint32
```

I group them by the first two columns and apply a function, like this:

```py
df1 = df1.groupby(["A", "B"]).apply(my_function, meta={"Res_1":"uint32", "Res_2":"float32", "Res_3":"float32"})
df2 = df2.groupby(["A", "B"]).apply(my_function, meta={"Res_1":"uint32", "Res_2":"float32", "Res_3":"float32"})
```

The resulting two dataframes have three columns, and an index composed of two terms (originally, the A and B columns). They look like this:

```
                          Res_1       Res_2       Res_3
A        B                                   
chrA01   1                    0    0.000000    0.000000
         5001                 0    0.000000    0.000000
         35001             2656    0.967225   21.346008
         55001              261    1.000000   27.003832
chrC01   1                  131    0.411950    8.610687
...                         ...         ...         ...
         10001                0    0.000000    0.000000
chrA01   30001             1511    1.000000   25.416943
         90001             1407    1.000000   25.073915
chrC01   30001                0    0.000000    0.000000
         90001                0    0.000000    0.000000
```

I then want to merge them into one dataframe, using a union of the `df1` and `df2` index, so I use the `how="outer"` option `on=["A", "B"]`.

```py
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", on=["A", "B"], validate="one_to_one")
```

However, I get this error since I am doing `validate="one_to_one"`:

```py
pandas.errors.MergeError: Merge keys are not unique in either left or right dataset; not a one-to-one merge
```

I know that the keys should be unique, because I have assessed the generation of the two dataframes and their content.

Maybe I am doing the `merge()` wrongly? My suspect is on the way I specify the `on=...` option. Is there a way I can specify `on=index` even if it is an index with two terms?

Comment: What happens if you compare `len(df.index.values)` with `len(df.index.unique.values)`?

Comment: I get 134 for index and 44 for unique index (I think you meant `unique()` and not just `unique` right?). However, I have now edited in the question a little preview of how `df1` looks like pre-merge. You can easily see that each line has a different combination of A and B.

Comment: *"I then want to merge them into one dataframe, using a union of the df1 and df2 index"* this join instead merge. `df1.join(df2, how='outer')` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: @ansev I just tried with join but didn't get anything better. It still produces two rows for each index (e.g. for the first line that has `chrA01` and `1` I get two lines with that same index, in the joined `df`).

Comment: @Macspider you say that the dataframe indices are unique, but the comparison of `len(df.index.values)` with `len(df.index.unique().values)` suggests otherwise.  What happens if you use `df[df.index.duplicated()]`?

Comment: I found the solution and it had to do with another issue, not what I thought when I wrote the post. I'm going to rewrite the post a little, so that future readers could benefit from my mistake. Thanks all of you for the suggestions, they made me find what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestions to look into the indexes and unique indexes, I found the issue. When performing `groupby()` on both `A` and `B`, the function called with `apply()` returned one line with the right results and one full of `NaN` values. The reason is yet to be determined.

Due to a weird output sorting, these two outputs were not one after the other in the dataframes. Hence I did not see the second `NaN` lines when writing this post.

After generating the dataframes, I now run a `df.dropna(how="all")` for each and the duplicated indexes are gone. I feel like this is not a clean solution, as those `NaN` lines should not even be there in the first place, but for now I found this patch.